# UPDATE QUERY in PHP there's no error but its not working

Tags: php, html

I dont what is the wrong about this, theres no error but its not working about the update query. I dont know if its the latest code or old code. Please tell me how can I fix this. Thanks, here's the code. The first code is the server.php

here's the structure:

```
    <?php 

        session_start();

         $username = "";
         $password = "";
         $lastname = "";
         $firstname = "";
         $id = 0;
         $edit_state = false;


        //connect to the database
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'login');

        // button is clicked
        if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
            $username = $_POST['text_username'];
            $password = $_POST['text_password'];
            $lastname = $_POST['text_lastname'];
            $firstname = $_POST['text_firstname'];
            //adding data in to database
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, lastname, firstname) values ('$username', '$password', '$lastname', '$firstname')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Account Saved!";
            header('location: acc-settings.php');
        }


        //update records in the database
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['text_username']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
            $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
            $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
            $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

            mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET username = '$username', password = '$password', lastname = '$lastname', firstname = '$firstname' where id='$id'");
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Account Updated!";
            header('location: acc-settings.php');
        }
        //retrieve records
        $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users"); ?>
```

this is the acc-settings.php

```
    <?php include 'server.php';

        //fetching the record
        if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
            $id = $_GET['edit'];

            $rec = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users where id=$id");
            $record = mysqli_fetch_array($rec);
            $username = $record['username'];
            $password = $record['password'];
            $lastname = $record['lastname'];
            $firstname = $record['firstname'];
            $id = $record['id'];
        }

             ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Account Settings</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/acc-style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])): ?>
            <div class="msg">
                <?php 
                echo $_SESSION['msg']; 
                unset($_SESSION['msg']);
                 ?>
            </div>

            <?php endif ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>

                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="acc-settings.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } ?>



     </tbody>
   </table>
   <form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="text_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="text_username" value="<?php echo 
   $username; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="text_password" value="<?php echo 
    $password; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="text_lastname" value="<?php echo 
    $lastname; ?>">`enter code here`
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="text_firstname" value="<?php echo 
    $firstname; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <?php if ($edit_state == true): ?>
        <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn">Save</button>
    <?php else: ?>
        <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn">Update</button>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Please tell me what is the wrong of this code :( if the problem is not understandable please comment down. Thankyou so much!

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Add a check on the update statement.  There should be an error

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can I apply that code in my code? ;(

Comment: @Akintunde i already check it in w3schools but its correct I dont know what wrong

Comment: The where clause in the update query has the id in quotes, but it is an integer. Cast the variable to integer (you really should use parameterized queries instead) and remove the quotes. Not sure if that is the issue but its an issue. If the update is well formed but the where clause results in no records updated, it is not an error that would be reported by the database.

Comment: _how can I apply that code in my code?_ By reading the pages linked to in my commeny

Comment: You should be using $_POST['text_id'] no $_POST['id']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see mismatch in names of form inputs and $_POST keys. For example

```
<input type="hidden" name="text_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

name="text_id", but $_POST['id'] using, not $_POST['text_id']

Many other fields have same problem.

Comment: im sorry but I forgot to change, but I know that syntax. But its not working also... :(

Comment: wait, what is the right syntax about that? The name of the textbot or the row in my database? Thankyou :)